# Create new file type HOW TO

Tags: windows, file, contextmenu, new-operator

Could you help me please. In windows context menu there is a sub menu - "CREATE NEW". When it opens there is a list of items you can create: text file, folder, shortcut and so on.

1. How can I get the list of the items? (Add them to a StringList)
2. How can I programmatically create any of them (.txt, folder is not a problem) for example BRIEFCASE????

For example: I want to get the list of the items and then dynamically create TButton for each of them so that when you click a button the item(File type) assigned to the button is created.